# Show/hide the sections, subsections and subsections that I want from the navigation sidebar (beamer, Berkeley)

Tags: beamer, sectioning, table-of-contents, navigation

I am using the theme `Berkeley`, I have lot of sections and subsections, I want to hide certain sections, subsections and subsubsections from the navigation bar, but not from the table of contents.

If I use `\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Berkeley}`, then it will hide all the subsections from the navigation bar. I need to hide the the section, subsection, the subsubsection I want. How could I do that?

Answer (score 10):

Use the optional argument of the sectioning commands and leave it empty to not include the unit in the sidebar; the unit will, however, be included in the ToC; an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection[]{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\section[]{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection[]{Test Subsection Three One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The ToC:

[image]

and one of the frames with hidden units in the sidebar:

[image]