# How to hide other SubSubsections in sidebar of beamerclass?

Tags: beamer, templates, navigation

I make a translation of a 600 pages Book with the beamer class in Latex, so I have lots of Subsections and SubSubsections. I want to show all subsections of the current Section in the sidebar along with all the subsubsections of the CURRENT subsection.
I came across a hint and made

```
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}
{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
```

But that just hides all subsubsections but the current one. The best solution would be something like

```
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}[subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
```

or any other way i can change the subsubsectionstyle.
The best idea I had was

```
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}
{\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]}
```

But that just creates over 3000 errors and didn't solved my problem . Is there anybody who has an idea to solve this Problem ?

Here is a MWE to show what i mean:

```
    \documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Goettingen}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection1.1.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 1.1.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection1.2.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 1.2.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 2}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection2.1.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 2.1.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection2.2.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 2.2.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And one page of the output is:
[image]

As you can see, with the option [hideothersubsections] in 
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Goettingen} subsections outside the current section are not shown in the sidebar. I want the same effect for the subsubsections with regard to subsections. So Subsubsection1.2.1 and SubSubsection1.2.2 should not be seen in the sidebar, because im in subsection 1.1

Therefore it should looks like this:
[image]

And when my slides move on and the subsections changes (from subec 1.1 to subsec 1.2), then the displayed subsubsection shall also change.
It then should looks like this:
[image]

Of course the space between subsec 1.1 and subsec 1.2 should disappear.

Comment: I think you can refer to [Show/hide the sections, subsections and subsections that I want from the navigation sidebar (beamer, Berkeley)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51647)

Comment: Theres one hitch. Subsubsection which are declared with \subsubsection[]{...} would never be shown in my sidebar. But the point is, the list of subsubsections shall change with the current subsection.

Comment: Can you provide the simplest example with dummy 2 sections and 2 subsections, subsubsections each etc? It would demonstrate the problem much clearer and would give us a chance to work on it right away.

Comment: done, I hope this helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/hide the sections, subsections and subsections that I want from the navigation sidebar (beamer, Berkeley)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51647/show-hide-the-sections-subsections-and-subsections-that-i-want-from-the-navigat)

Comment: In my topic there is a slightly difference in the problem. I dont want a static hide of my subsubsection. My intention is,just to show the subsubsection of the current subsection in my sidebar. All other subsubsections should be hidden. BUT, and here is the Point. When my Presentation continues and my slides move on, my subsection will change. And then it shall again just show the subsubsections of the current subsection, but these will be different subsubsections than before. These subsubsections were previously hidden in the subsection before. The link unfortunatly don't solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it's enough to use the `hideothersubsections` option of `\usetheme` command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multido}

\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{PaloAlto}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{2}{%
  \section{Section}
  \multido{\i=1+1}{5}{%
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{3}{%
      \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
      \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Foo}
        Bar.
      \end{frame}
    }
  }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does also work with (some) other theme commands. For example, for the sidebar I am using `\useoutertheme[height=0pt,width=2cm,right,hideothersubsections]{sidebar}` to only show the current subsections.

Answer (score 1):

I've bumped into the same problem. Here's how I solved it. (an ugly hack, but works quite well for me.)

Locate 'beamerbasenavigation.sty' in the `beamer` package. Search for the definition of the `\insertverticalnavigation` command.
Copy this code into the preempt part of your document.

Inside the function, change

```
\def\beamer@subsubsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
  \ifnum##1=\c@part%
  \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
```

to

```
\def\beamer@subsubsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
  \ifnum##1=\c@part%
  \ifnum##2=\c@section
  \ifnum##3=\c@subsection
  \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
```

This ensures that the subsubsection entry appears only when both section number and subsection number match the current ones.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: BTW, don't forget to add the corresponding '\fi' at the end....

Comment: Worked for me too, but I skipped the `\ifnum##3=\c@subsection` part.