# Beamer -- Showing subsections for the current section in sidebar

Tags: beamer, sectioning, navigation

I have a lot of subsections in my beamer presentation and there is a sidebar in my theme.
I prefer to show the list of subsections only if their parent section is active. In this way less space will be taken by the items in the sidebar.

I searched for similar questions. But none of them were the one I was looking for.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: have you tried `hideothersubsections` as a theme option?

Comment: You might also look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51647/show-hide-the-sections-subsections-and-subsections-that-i-want-from-the-navigat

Comment: @dcmst I'm not using beamer's default themes. I have designed my theme but I use sidebar theme from beamer. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Try to use `hideothersubsections` as a global option: `\documentclass[hideothersubsections]{beamer}`.

Comment: @dcmst That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: @AryaMz You're welcome, I converted my comments into an answer so that we can remove this question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option `hideothersubsections` works for sidebar themes and can be used both with the theme specification, as in:

```
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Hannover}
```

or as a global option, as in:

```
\documentclass[hideothersubsections]{beamer}
```

In both cases it hides the subsections of the non active sections from the sidebar.